# Accessible Citation for the associative based loop space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, loop-spaces

John Moore defined a based loop space using maps of intervals [0,r].
It was defined in a samizdat version of the Milnor-Moore paper on Hopf algebra, but was cut in the published version. Is there a usable citation?

Comment: I notice in "Stable Homotopy and Iterated Loop Spaces" by Carlsson-Milgram they define Moore loops and verify some basic properties.

Comment: Thankswill checck it out